# Get value from other model without any association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models and tables Products, Customers, Buyers and there are has_and_belongs_to_many relationship among them. And I have another model and table sells. I need to get value from all of the above 3 tables in sells/new page. Do I have to use any association among them? How can I get the values?

I want product_id, product_name, customer_id, customer_name in views/sells/new.html.erb file I don't understand how can I get that

Comment: Do you mean something like sells.each do |sell|  sell.product sell.customer sell.buyer end ??

Comment: I want product_id, product_name, customer_id, customer_name in views/sells/new.html.erb file  I don't understand how can I get that

Comment: You need to associate the moels with each other first.

Answer (score 0):

Add `user_id` and `product_id` to sells table

```
Class User
    has_many :sells
end

Class Product
    has_many :sells
end

Class Sells
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Then do on sell show page

```
sell.user_id
sell.user.name

sell.product_id
sell.product.name
```

Hope this is what you need or least give an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all it should be `sales` table and the `Sale` model. But anyway, from the view (or helper), you can do:

```
Product.all # gives you all products
# or fetch just the columns you want:
Product.select( [:id, :name] )
```

Same goes for customers (i.e. `Customer.all` etc.).

It's not an orthodox way to do it but it will work. With Erb you'll need `<% ... %>` or `<%= ... %>` of course.